# Как найти наименьшее значение в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение

Имеем двумерный массив, в подмассивах которого первым аргументом является значение ширины, вторым — высоты. К примеру,

```
$array = array(

//array(width, height),

array(30, 454),
array(903, 154),
array(361, 190),
);
```

Требуется из этого набора получить массив, содержащий наименьшее значение второго аргумента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дык просто перебором

```
$index = 0; // Сюда положим индекс с наименьшего значения
$minHeight = $array[0][1];
foreach($array as $key => $sArray) 
{
   if($sArray[1] < $minHeight)
   {
      $index     = $key;
      $minHeight = $sArray[1];
   }    
}
```